# MySQL select records with multiple joined objects with the same field value

Tags: mysql

Apologies for the title; my question is much clearer with the specific example.

I have two tables - one for people, and one for addresses. I've grouped them together and selected the relevant parts:

```
ID |  Address  | Address_Status
-------------------------------
1  | 2 Main St | Active
1  | 19 Elm Rd | Inactive
1  | 7 Red Ave | Active
2  | 9 Gold St | Inactive
2  | 3 Rich St | Inactive
```

I'm trying to select IDs of people who have all Inactive addresses. This means that in the output, the only record should be ID = 2. I've tried grouping them by ID, then using a `having (count(*) - count(Address_Status = 'I')) = 0`, which is as close as I've come.

Comment: If you have two separate tables, keep them separate in your code sample. Makes it easier for people to answer your question that way, since your question is on the join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user has no addresses at all they should be omitted yes?
In that case I'd favor something like:

```
SELECT People.ID, People.Name, 
SUM(IF(Addresses.Address_Status = 'I', 1, 0)) AS InactiveCount, 
SUM(IF(Addresses.Address_Status != 'I', 1, 0)) AS ActiveCount, 
FROM People JOIN Addresses ON Addresses.personID = People.ID
GROUP BY People.ID
HAVING ActiveCount = 0 AND InactiveCount > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to join the address table and return only values with no active record existed:

```
Select P.* from People P
left join (Select * from addresses where Address_status="ACTIVE") A
on P.id=A.pid
where A.pid is null;
```

The drawback here is that you would also return any user that had no address registered to their account, which might not be the intended behavior.